# Why does the ? operator report the error "the trait bound NoneError: Error is not satisfied"?

Tags: error-handling, rust

The [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) at line 9 works OK, but if I use the same logic on the same type in line 19, it blows up.

```
use std::error::Error;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let valid_entries = WalkDir::new("/tmp")
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|e| e)
        .flat_map(|e| {
            let name = e.file_name().to_str()?; // <-- this works
            if name.contains(".txt") {
                Some(e)
            } else {
                None
            }
        });

    for entry in valid_entries {
        println!("This file matches: {:?}", entry);
        let name_to_str = entry.file_name().to_str()?; // <-- this blows up
        // ...
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The errors are a little cryptic for me to interpret:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::NoneError: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:53
   |
26 |         let name_to_str = entry.file_name().to_str()?;
   |                                                     ^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `std::option::NoneError`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<std::option::NoneError>` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Why is the `?` operator blowing up while iterating `valid_entries`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `?` can be used to check-and-return any type that implements the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait (still unstable). The only implementations in `std` of those are `Option<T>` and `Result<T, E>` (plus some `Future`-related impls that are not relevant to this discussion). This means that you can use the `?` operator in any function that returns `Result<T, E>` or `Option<T>`.

But you cannot mix-n-match those. That is, if your function returns a `Result<T, E>` you cannot use the `?` in a value of type `Option<T>`. Or vice versa.

The reason your first `?` works is because you are inside a `flat_map()` that returns `Option<String>` and all goes well. The second one, however, is in a function that returns a `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` so you can't use `?` with an `Option<String>`.

The solution is simply to deal with the `None` in your `Option<String>` in another way:

1. Doing a `match` / `if let Some(x)` to handle the error separately.
2. Converting into a `Result<String, Error>` and use `?`, for example with `.ok_or(std::io::ErrorKind::InvalidData)?;`.
3. Similar to 2, but take advantage of the `impl From<&str> for Box<dyn Error>` and do `.ok_or("invalid file name")`.
4. Giving a default value, with `Option::unwrap_or()` or similar.
5. Doing `unwrap()` and panicking if `None`.

Ok, but what does this error mean? The idea is that actually you are able to use `?` with an `Option<T>` that returns a `Result<T, E>`, as long as your `E` implements `From<std::option::NoneError>`. Unfortunately, [`NoneError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/struct.NoneError.html) is still unstable, too, so you can't implement `From<NoneError>` in your code using the stable compiler. Nevertheless, the `E` in your code is `Box<dyn Error>`, and the compiler would be happy to do the boxing as long as `NoneError` implements `Error`, but...

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::NoneError: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
```

Comment: Great, explanation, offering multiple options. In my case I used option 3.

Comment: So, what's the solution in short.